# War loot bonus when lost

Tags: clash-of-clans

When I search players to attack in a clan war, the game shows me a certain war bonus on every player.

Lets say the bonus is: 300k Gold & Elixir, and 1k Dark Elixir.
This is what I get if we win the war & I get 3 stars.

How much is it reduced in lower stars?

How much is it reduced when the war is lost with different stars?

Source on answers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[You get 3/7 times of the available loot if your clan loses the war.](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Wars#War_Results)

> For a Victory you would earn the full War Win bonus. For a draw you would earn half of the war win bonus, and for a Defeat you would earn only 3/7ths of the war win bonus. As of the newest 2018 update states.

The 'war win bonus' is rewarded in full to you and then the percentage above is applied.

So if you obtained a bonus of 700k gold, you would get 700k gold no matter how many stars you scored if your clan wins. You'd get 350k gold if your clan draws and 300k gold otherwise.

---

<strike>[You get 40% of the available loot if your clan loses the war.](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Wars#War_Results)</strike>

> For a Victory you would earn the full War Win bonus. For a draw you would earn half of the war win bonus, and for a Defeat you would earn only 3/7ths of the war win bonus. As of the newest 2017 update states.

Though there's one thing I want to clear up: the 'war win bonus' is rewarded in full to you and then the percentage above is applied. The number of stars you get on a base has no influence on this. Source is personal experience. I have 'town hall sniped' (which gives 1 star) a lot of times just because of this because my clan was winning the war by far and the other clan was mostly inactive so chances that they catch up was close to nil and I really needed resources for major upgrades. So whenever a clan is inactive attack straight away. Otherwise I would advise you to let them attack first.

So if you have a bonus of 100k gold, you would get 100k gold no matter how many stars you scored if your clan wins. You'd get 70k gold if your clan draws and 40k gold otherwise, all this irrespective of the number of stars you scored.

Note that if you score no stars, you won't get any bonus (the bonus won't appear at the top left of your screen).

Comment: Note: the war bonus percentage has been updated from 20% to 30% recently, following the Halloween update. And the wiki might be wrong, but I believe that draws now gives 50%. I remember experiencing that I got more war loot than the 40% I expected, but I can't find any source.

Comment: so even if I destroy only 50% of the enemy base, I get the full war loot reward if my team wins the war right?

Comment: @Esq That's right!

Comment: Though, do try to get 100% when you can so your clan has more chances to win the war.

Comment: so if my clan is already really far ahead, there is no reason to make 10xdragon army? instead just try to snipe the outside buldings. no harm for me or my clan correct?

Comment: @Esq Yup, you can do that. I always ask my clanmates before doing that though. Usually they're cool with that :)

Comment: Also, if you have a townhall way outside the defenses, you can aim for that since this automatically gives you 1 star for the win.

Comment: ok thanks. update the post please if you figure out new data. and you might want to check this out: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/196362/donating-troops-in-war-not-counting

Comment: @Esq Will do, since draws are quite rare though (and I'd prefer a win over a draw for sure!), it might take some time.

Comment: @Esq Coincidentally, my clan just drew, and the loot is indeed 40% now.

Comment: [Has this changed recently?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/297063/132901)

Answer (score 1):

You only keep 30% of your bonus loot according to the wiki's section on [War Results](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Wars#War_Results) if you lose the clan war. If it's a draw, then you only keep 40%. If you win, then you get 100% of the bonus loot.

The amount of stars you earn during the course of the war doesn't matter in the overall bonus loot reduction.

An example would be say I got 500,000 Gold/Elixir and 3,000 Dark Elixir. If we won I wound get all of the loot. If we tied, then I would only get 200,000 Gold/Elixir and 1,200 Dark Elixir. If we lost I would only get 120,000 Gold/Elixir and 900 Dark Elixir.

Comment: well this is a programmed game, there is a percentage somewhere and someone knows it.

Comment: I will look further into the matter.