# Donating troops in war not counting?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I see that donating troops in clan wars do not count in my overall troops donated count. Why is this? Is there a way to track who donated how much troops in clans wars?

Answer (score 3):

The reason why the game developers did this is stated in [this post](https://gamesupport.supercell.net/hc/en-us/articles/203201283), I will quote the part:

> We’d like to make sure your clan mates donate Clan War troops for a single purpose: **to win the War**. We want Clashers to be motivated by the cause, and *not for gems and achievements*, as we believe not doing so would encourage people to donate troops that nobody needs.

And no, there's no way to track who donated how many troops. The best you can do is try to guess who gave those troops by comparing the level of the donated troops and the unlocked levels of each clan member.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell who has donated by either looking at the levels of the troops donated, or looking to see who has different cc troops to everyone else.

There will be an obvious difference in the user who donated to everyone else as they can't donate to themselves.

Comment: I tried to fix the grammar on this, and then realised I couldn't actually understand what you meant. It would be good if you could improve this to a more readable level.

Comment: Yeah, I concur, I had a crack too and I'm afraid I don't quite follow. Can you rephrase this into a few sentences?