# Do you get war bonus for an attack that you lose?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I just lost an attack in clan war (0 stars), but the status up in the corner says I got some bonus (about a third of what I would get for win).
This was my first attack in the war.

Earlier this has been like that you will get no bonus for an attack that you loose in the war. Has this changed recently?

I am sure that this happened to me, I mainly want to know when this change was introduced, and details about percentages etc. Is it 30% or something if you loose, or is it also dependent on how much of the base you have destroyed (like if you destroy 20%, you will get 20% bonus or something..)?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. I'll have to actually lose an attack to confirm xD

Comment: I guess you don't want to intentionally loose an attack just to answer my question... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened to me again. I got 0 stars in a war attack!

This time I noticed that in the status screen after the ended attack, it specifically said that I earned 43% of the war bonus. I also noticed that I had destroyed 43% of the base, so it seems this is directly related to how much of the base is destroyed.

**CONFIRMED**:
See [Clash of Clans Wikia - Clan Wars](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Wars) and scroll down to the **War Win Bonus** section:

> If you get no stars in an attack, you only get a reduced bonus whose percentage is equal to the destruction percentage. For example, an attack of 30% without destroying the Town Hall will give 30% of the full War Win Bonus of this base.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you still get a war bonus if you lose its just smaller than it would originally be lets say you had a loot bonus of both 500000 gold and elixir know if you won that war then yes you would get 500000 gold and elixir but if you lost then it would be smaller hope i answered your answer to your classifications and have a great day.

Comment: You're actually answering a different question. This question is asking about earning *any* loot bonus at all when making a 0 star attack on a war base. Apparently, the asker still managed to earn some loot bonus for the attack despite scoring 0 stars.